# How is it breaking out of the for loop in this C++ code?

Tags: c++

Here is the code:

```
for (int i=0;i<someClass::someList.entries();i++)
    returnBool |= (someOtherClass.get_something() == 
                  ((someClass*)(someClass::someList[i]))->get_something_else());
```

What I think it does, it iterates through all instance i.e. ptr of someClass held in someList. and if get_something() == get_something_else() then we assign value 1 to returnBool, otherwise 0 as its a bitwise OR operator.

However in debugger what I'm noticing is that, regardless of how long someList is, it is breaking out of the for loop as soon as returnBool is 1 - does that sound right?

Thanks for your time =]

Comment: Possibly a smart compiler optimized in a break after `returnBool` first becomes non-0?

Comment: @Cameron that largely depends on `get_something` and the rest of the operations.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Sounds strange to exit the loop for a compiler optimization!

Answer (score 3):

Actually, as soon as `returnBool` is `true`, no amount of `|=` will make it `false`, because `true | false == true`.

You can actually safely break from the loop the first time `returnBool` is `true` (unless the methods `get_something` are mutating, which, by their name, are not).

Comment: And I think this is basically an `any_of` check.

Comment: @Xeo nice! Didn't know that existed. Add answer!

Comment: I meant the concept, not the `std::any_of` algorithm. :)

Comment: @Xeo well, `std::any_of` exists (which is what I was saying nice about). As for the concept, yes, it's pretty obvious.

Comment: A good example of why non-mutating methods should be `const`. If `get_something()` or `get_something_else()` were not `const`, the compiler would probably be unable to apply this optimisation.

Comment: @Gorpik not even then. They can be non-mutating and still have side-effects. I think relying on the compiler for this optimization is far-fetched - I wouldn't expect it to do it.

Comment: @Luchian: on the pedantic side, whether the `const` makes a difference or not depends whether `returnBool` is a _local_ variable of the method the above code is in, or a _class member_. If it's a local, the optimization to break the loop on first-`true` is always applicable.

Comment: @FrankH. not really. What if `get_something` prints something on the screen?

Comment: I thought the compiler was allowed to consider that a `const` function would not have any side effects for optimisation purposes, but it looks like I am wrong. This must be a linker optimisation. I have tried using a `const` - non `const` function, in both cases printing - not printing to screen, and it only optimises the calls for the non printing version, regardless of the function constness.

Comment: @Gorpik exactly what I'm saying. `const` doesn't affect observed behavior.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Sorry, my comment intended intended to say yours was right, but I worded it poorly.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input and discussion. Both get_something and get_something_else are virtual const methods that return an int. We are basically comparing to see if the id exists in the other list, if it does, then that is something of interest to us. We're using vanilla GNU compiler on linux. I don't think it is breaking out of loop due to any_of, as we are using STL version 5.1. At first I had a feeling that this was not an intended outcome of the loop. But now I feel pretty certain about it. I'll dig around more and update here if I find anything. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a compiler optimization. I assume that these functions were simple enough that it could see that they have no side-effects.

If you are sure that you can skip them, I suggest making this optimization more visible and mandatory for other less smart compiler (or human):

```
for (int i=0;i<someClass::someList.entries() && !returnBool;i++)
    returnBool |= (someOtherClass.get_something() == 
                  ((someClass*)(someClass::someList[i]))->get_something_else());
```

Alternatively, if the compiler was wrong (unlikely) or you wish to make clear that you want to test the whole list, just do this:

```
for (int i=0;i<someClass::someList.entries();i++)
    returnInt += (someOtherClass.get_something() == 
                  ((someClass*)(someClass::someList[i]))->get_something_else());
return returnInt > 0;
```